# Zoom Google chart - querySelector

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I would like so much to learn how to solve this puzzle: The function zoom is not working, I tried everything... I don't know what to do... I can't figure out what is missing in the code.

I would like to share one example that's working:
[http://jsfiddle.net/0wb2zvye/3/][1]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>
    Google Visualization API Sample
  </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"> {lang: 'en-US'}</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart', 'controls'],'language': 'en-US'});
  </script>

 </head>
 <style>

</style>

<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">

        <div id="dashboard" style="width:1350px;overflow:scroll;">

     Zoom<br />
    <input id="lastA" type="button" value="Mon" />
    <input id="lastB" type="button" value="Tue" />
    <input id="lastC" type="button" value="Wed" />
    <input id="lastD" type="button" value="Thu" />
    <input id="lastE" type="button" value="Fri" />
    <input id="lastF" type="button" value="Sat" />
    <input id="lastG" type="button" value="Sun" />    

            <div id="chart" style="position: relative; width: 1350px; height: 500px;"></div>
            <div id="control" style='width: 1350px; height: 50px;'></div>
            <div id="filter_div"></div>

        </div>

        <div id="junk_div" style="display: none;"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

var data;
var dataTable;
var dashboard;

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["controls", "corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function setupData(){

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'control',
        'options': {
            // Filter by the date axis.
            'filterColumnIndex': 0,
            'ui': {
                'chartType': 'LineChart',
                'chartOptions': {
                    'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
                    'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
                },
                'chartView': {
                    'columns': [0, 1, 2]
                },
                'minRangeSize': 1
            }
        },
        // Initial range: 1 to 4.
        'state': {'range': {'start': 1, 'end': 50}},
        view: {
            columns: [{
                type: 'number',
                calc: function (dt, row) {
                    return {v: row, f: dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0)};
                }
            }, 1, 2]
        }
    });



    //then reverse the process in the ChartWrapper's view.columns:
    var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'E \nHH:mm', 'textStyle':{'fontSize': 8}});
    dateFormatter.format(data, 0);


    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'AreaChart',
        'containerId': 'chart',
        'options': {
           'title':'Wharehouse overwiew',
            // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
            'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '90%'},
            'vAxis': {'viewWindowMode':'explicit','viewWindow': {'min': 0},'gridlines': { 'count': 10, 'color': '#d9e2d9' } ,'textStyle':{'fontSize': 11}},
             'legend': { 'position': 'top', 'alignment': 'start' },
             'hAxis': {'format': 'E /nHH:mm','textStyle':{'fontSize': 8},'minTextSpacing': 0, 'slantedText': false},
             'tooltip': { 'textStyle': { 'fontName': 'verdana', 'fontSize': 10, 'color': '#2d862d' } },
             'series': {
    0: { 'areaOpacity': 0.1},
    1: { 'areaOpacity': 0.1}
}


//        'trendlines': {0: {'color': 'black','lineWidth': 3,'opacity': 0.4 }}

// hAxis: {   'minTextSpacing': 0,  'showTextEvery': 1,  slantedText: true }
        },
        view: {
            columns: [{
                type: 'string',
                label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
                calc: function (dt, row) {
                    return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0);
                }
            }, 1, 2]
        }
    });
    console.log('label: ' + data.getColumnLabel(0));


    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.querySelector('#dashboard'));


    dashboard.bind(control, chart).bind(filter, control);
    dashboard.draw(data);

    function zoomLastA () {
        var range = data.getColumnRange(0);
        control.setState({
            range: {
                start: new Date(range.max.getFullYear(), range.max.getMonth(), range.max.getDate() - 1),
                end: range.max
            }
        });
        control.draw();
    }

    function zoomLastB () {
        var range = data.getColumnRange(0);
        control.setState({
            range: {
                start: new Date(range.max.getFullYear(), range.max.getMonth(), range.max.getDate() - 2),
                end: range.max
            }
        });
        control.draw();
    }


    function zoomLastC () {
        var range = data.getColumnRange(0);
        control.setState({
            range: {
                start: new Date(range.max.getFullYear(), range.max.getMonth(), range.max.getDate() -3),
                end: range.max
            }
        });
        control.draw();
    }

    function zoomLastD () {
        var range = data.getColumnRange(0);
        control.setState({
            range: {
                start: new Date(range.max.getFullYear(), range.max.getMonth(), range.max.getDate() -4),
                end: range.max
            }
        });
        control.draw();
    }

    function zoomLastE () {
        var range = data.getColumnRange(0);
        control.setState({
            range: {
                start: new Date(range.max.getFullYear(), range.max.getMonth(), range.max.getDate() -5),
                end: range.max
            }
        });
        control.draw();
    }

    function zoomLastF () {
        var range = data.getColumnRange(0);
        control.setState({
            range: {
                start: new Date(range.max.getFullYear(), range.max.getMonth(), range.max.getDate() -6),
                end: range.max
            }
        });
        control.draw();
    }

    function zoomLastG () {
        var range = data.getColumnRange(0);
        control.setState({
            range: {
                start: new Date(range.max.getFullYear(), range.max.getMonth(), range.max.getDate() -7),
                end: range.max
            }
        });
        control.draw();
    }

    var runOnce = google.visualization.events.addListener(dashboard, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.removeListener(runOnce);

        if (document.addEventListener) {
            document.querySelector('#lastA').addEventListener('click', zoomLastA);
            document.querySelector('#lastB').addEventListener('click', zoomLastB);
            document.querySelector('#lastC').addEventListener('click', zoomLastC);
            document.querySelector('#lastD').addEventListener('click', zoomLastD);
            document.querySelector('#lastE').addEventListener('click', zoomLastE);
            document.querySelector('#lastF').addEventListener('click', zoomLastF);
            document.querySelector('#lastG').addEventListener('click', zoomLastG);

        }
        else if (document.attachEvent) {
            document.querySelector('#lastA').attachEvent('onclick', zoomLastA);
            document.querySelector('#lastB').attachEvent('onclick', zoomLastB);
            document.querySelector('#lastC').attachEvent('onclick', zoomLastC);
            document.querySelector('#lastD').attachEvent('onclick', zoomLastD);
            document.querySelector('#lastE').attachEvent('onclick', zoomLastE);
            document.querySelector('#lastF').attachEvent('onclick', zoomLastF);
            document.querySelector('#lastG').attachEvent('onclick', zoomLastG);

        }
        else {
            document.querySelector('#lastA').onclick = zoomLastA;
            document.querySelector('#lastB').onclick = zoomLastB;
            document.querySelector('#lastC').onclick = zoomLastC;
            document.querySelector('#lastD').onclick = zoomLastD;
            document.querySelector('#lastE').onclick = zoomLastE;
            document.querySelector('#lastF').onclick = zoomLastF;
            document.querySelector('#lastG').onclick = zoomLastG;

        }
    });    



}

function drawVisualization() {

  dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();


  dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('#dashboard'));
```